# how to directly drive the PC speaker in linux

Tags: linux, x86

On the original IBM PC, you could directly drive the PC speaker by writing ones and zeroes to bit 1 of I/O address 0x61; it was basically a 1-bit DAC running at a timer frequency of 1.19 MHz (system clock of 4.77MHz, divided by 4).

Is there a way to do this in linux? Ideally, I'd like to have a serial device that I could just feed a file or a real-time bitstream to, and have it connected directly to the TTL speaker voltage pin on the motherboard. Most of the stuff I've seen online programs clock 2 of the PIT via ioctls, but I want to drive the speaker directly, not via the timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a kernel module called `snd-pcsp` that exactly tries to do that (source code is in `sound/drivers/pcsp/`, you can see how it addresses port 0x61). It's exposed as an ALSA device, so it's easy to feed a real-time bitstream to it.

However, on my system, the sound it produces audibly doesn't resemble very much what you put it, at least not the one thing I tried. But you didn't say what you want to use it for.
I also don't think you can go up to 1.19 MHz. But you can always modify the kernel module to suit it to your needs.

If that doesn't work, nothing stops you from writing to port 0x61 if your user space application is root and can execute `ioperm`. But then of course you have the problem that Linux is not a realtime OS, and your application may be preempted at any time. (And I'd be interested in ways to prevent this, too, like reserving one core for this particular application).

Comment: There's another reason the sound might not be what you expect. The non-ancient motherboards I've seen integrate the PC speaker (where they don't just redirect it to the integrated sound card), and the output device actually seems to be some sort of buzzer, not a proper speaker.

Comment: @sourcejedi In my case, it's a proper speaker: It's an ancient tower case (though the motherboard has changed a few times), and the very same speaker has successfully played sound for DOS games back in the day. :-)